# iTunes Connect: App description for multiple types of a particular language?

Tags: app-store-connect

Is there a fast way to take an app description written in English and apply it to all English languages?? (Ex: Canadian English, UK English.)

I don't want to create separate ones for each type of English because they will all be the same. I also want to do this for French.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The localization distinctions exist for a reason. They are *not* all the same.  If you've done your app in American English, specify American English and put that as the only language you're supporting because -- that's the only language you're supporting!

If you want to go through and do proper British English and Canadian English localizations, then I suggest you start with the video/slides for "WWDC 2012 Session 224 - Internationalization Tips and Tricks".

Why?   Because British and Canadian English speakers might find so little "humour" in your attempts to pass off your American English "localisations" as native that they'll likely put some "colourful" language into your app reviews.

That's why.

Also?  Aluminium.